# How to use facts/variables defined for one playbook in another?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Lets say I have a playbook like below

```
- name: install nagios client
  hosts: client1
  roles:
    - nagios-client
  set_fact:
    client_ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    client_hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"

- name: register client
  hosts: server
  vars:
    - ip: {{ client_ip }}
    - hostname: {{ client_hostname }}
  role:
    - register-nagios-client
```

I know that set_fact is bound to one host and cannot be used in another, also that you can get the IP of the client from facts `{{ hostvars['client1']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}`. But is there a work around to define a local variable that can be referenced in multiple places in the yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Facts are bound to hosts not plays, and remain defined for the life of a playbook being run.

You seem to already know how to refer to facts from another host, so just use it. Either (if you retain `set_fact` in the first playbook):

```
vars:
  - ip: "{{ hostvars['hostname'][client_ip] }}"
  - hostname: "{{ hostvars['hostname'][client_hostname] }}"
```

Or (because there seems to be no need to set the facts in the first play):

```
vars:
  - ip: "{{ hostvars['hostname'][ansible_default_ipv4][address] }}"
  - hostname: "{{ hostvars['hostname'][ansible_hostname] }}"
```

I used `hostname` above to refer to the host you wanted. `client1` in your playbook is a host group. It might or might not match the name of the host. It might also resolve to multiple hosts.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is an automated way to use that 'client1' name for the second playbook. Like a local variable or something which can be defined at one place in the playbook and referenced in multiple places.

Comment: `client1` in your example is a host group name (host pattern). It might resolve to a single host matching the group name, single host not matching the group name, or multiple hosts. You are trying to solve an XY problem.

Comment: In my use case, it only matches a single host (not a group).

Comment: Sorry, the issue you are trying to solve makes no sense to me. Please proceed solving on your own, or wait for someone who would grasp your objectives.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. My question is if I can define a local variable, lets say `client: client1` in my yml file and use that at several places. In this case, in three locations `hosts: {{ client }}`, `ip: "{{ hostvars[{{ client }}][ansible_default_ipv4][address] }}"` and `hostname: "{{ hostvars[{{ client }}][ansible_hostname] }}"`. Currently I have to use that reference multiple times, though its not a big deal.